# How do I remove the last vowel in a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, remove-method

How can I define the -last vowel- in a string?

For example, I have a word "classic"

I want to find that the last vowel of the word "classs**i**c" is the letter "**i**", and delete that last vowel.

I'm thinking :

```
def vowel(str)
  result = ""
  new = str.split(" ")
  i = new.length - 1
  while i < new.length
    if new[i] == "aeiou"
      new[i].gsub(/aeiou/," ")
    elsif new[i] != "aeiou"
      i = -= 1
    end
  end
  return result
end
```

Comment: Reverse the string, remove the first vowel, then reverse the string back.

Comment: You might want to edit your first sentence to remove the reference to Java.

Comment: Another way is `str = "fabulous"; str[str.rindex(/[aeiou]/)] = ''
 => ""; str #=> "fabulos"`, or `str.dup.tap { |s| s[s.rindex(/[aeiou]/)] = '' }` if `str` is not to be mutated.

Answer (score 13):

```
r = /
    .*      # match zero or more of any character, greedily
    \K      # discard everything matched so far
    [aeiou] # match a vowel
    /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

"wheelie".sub(r,'') #=> "wheeli"
"though".sub(r,'')  #=> "thogh"
"why".sub(r,'')     #=> "why"
```

Comment: That is a much better answer. Beautiful RegEx!

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Could you please provide a link, where `\K` is explained? I didn't find this at in the [Ruby Docs for Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html).

Comment: @user1934428 it's missing from the Ruby documentation, but http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html explains it.

Comment: @cary - this is a great explanation!

Answer (score 4):

Like @aetherus pointed out: reverse the string, remove the first vowel then reverse it back:

```
str = "classic"
=> "classic"
str.reverse.sub(/[aeiou]/, "").reverse
=> "classc"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
regex = /[aeiou](?=[^aeiou]*\z)/
```

- `[aeiou]` matches one vowel
- `[^aeiou]*` matches non-vowel characters 0 or more times
- `\z` matches to the end of the string
- `(?=...)` is positive forward looking and not including the match in the final result.

Here are a few examples:

```
"classic".sub(regex, '') #=> "classc"
  "hello".sub(regex, '') #=> "hell"
  "crypt".sub(regex, '') #=> "crypt
```