# `<=': comparison of Fixnum with Array failed (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby

In this code I am trying to remove the last vowel in the word. Once I ran the code, I received an argument error stating "comparison of Fixnum with Array failed(ArgumentError). Please help!

```
VOWELS = %w( a e i o u)

def hipsterfy(string)

  new_string = string.split('')

  reversed_string = new_string.reverse

  i = 0

  while i <= reversed_string

     if VOWELS.include?[i]

        reversed_string[i] = ('')

    i += 1
    end
    reversed_string
  end

  reversed_string.reverse 

end
```

Comment: Hint: If you run out of vowels does `i` get incremented? You also need to dig into regular expressions or, at the very least, the [`tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) method.

Comment: Correct indentation would almost certainly help you.

Comment: Though it does not answer your question, your problem is addressed in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628583/how-do-i-remove-the-last-vowel-in-a-string-in-ruby).

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure this is not the only glith with this code, but the error you got came from here:

```
while i <= reversed_string
```

it probably should be

```
while i < reversed_string.length
```

since `reversed_array` is an array, and you probably want to compare `i` against it’s `length`.

Answer (score 1):

When you test

```
if VOWELS.include?[i]
```

you're checking if the `VOWELS` constant includes the array index. You want to look at the letter at that point in the string instead, right?

```
if VOWELS.include?(reversed_string[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

There needed to be a "break" statement after the if statement to stop the loop as soon as it looped the first vowel. That would prevent it from going on to the next vowel. PROBLEM SOLVED.